# Fragments: how to change content?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a class that manages a fragment .. in a TextView I have to put the phone features, but because by mistake?

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, null);
        return view;
    }
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    String product = Build.PRODUCT;
    String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

    String scheda = model+"\n"+androidOS+" \n "+product+"";
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    text.setText(scheda);

    private TextView findViewById(int textview3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I did not understand a thing. I have three fragment, one of which is called Home, one faq and one about. How do I change the contents of the various "screens"?

Comment: Your initialization of textview is outside of any method. you have `findViewById` method defined. suggest you remove the same. and what is error?

Comment: I suggest you delete this question and try again.  Your subject talks about an error, but you have not said what the error is.  Then you tell use something you've done, which may or may not have something to do with the error, then you finish with a totally different question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cannot have operations on objects in the main class body without a helper method in java. I also see when you are creating a reference to you TextView, you need to find the TextView from your inflated view, so the right way to do it would be something like

TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

Lastly, when inflating the view, pass the ViewGroup as the parent for that view, and a false for the attachToRoot

You should have something like:

```
    public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_page,container,false);

    String model = Build.MODEL;
        String product = Build.PRODUCT;
        String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

        String scheda = model+"\n"+androidOS+" \n "+product+"";
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    text.setText(scheda);
return view;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: My app crash and the error is at line text.setText(scheda); Java NullPointerExceptio, why?

Comment: @Fiocchi, get your TextView like i did in my explaination, otherwise you will get a null pointer exception because you have not provided the view from which your textview resides, my quoted code had an error, i have edited it